# Clicking on button_to is not taking me to the intended method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get a button_to to call a controller. I've tried a number of variations and nothing seems to work.

In my index.html.erb, I have

```
  <%= button_to "Clear Search", { :controller => 'documents', :action => 'reset_search'}  %>
```

In my documents controller, I have

```
   helper_method :reset_search
      def reset_search
        @documents = Document.all
        $search = nil
        params[:search] = nil
        redirect_to documents_path
        $temp2 = 'testing 1 2 3'
      end
```

On the index, I put the following at the bottom.

```
$temp2 <%= $temp2 %>
```

Based on the $temp2 variable, I can see that I am not getting to the reset_search method when clicking the button as the contents of $temp2 are not changing

What do I need to do to actually have the button call the reset_search method?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax to call the method on click:

```
 $('.whatever-button-class').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/documents/reset_search', // make sure you have a route
      data: {
        // whatever data you want to send as key-value pairs
      }
   }).done(function(ajax_response){
      console.log(ajax_response)
   })
 })
```

Inside that controller action:

```
def reset_search
  # whatever you want to do
  render :json => {data: "Huzzah!"} # whatever data you want to pass back
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my button_to inside the other form tag. I moved it after the <% end %> and it is now working as expected.

```
      <%= form_tag documents_path, :method => 'get' do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
         <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      <% end %>

    <% if $search != ''  then %>
        <%= button_to "Clear Search", { :controller => 'documents', :action => 'reset_search'}  %>
    <% end %>
```